# Different GOPATH in bash terminal and in Goland IDE

Tags: linux, bash, go, ubuntu-18.04, goland

I've changed my `GOPATH` and in order to make the change persistent I've added the following line in my `.bashrc` file:

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/workspaces/go_projects
```

After restart, when I run `go env` in the bash terminal I see the correct path, but when I check in the GoLand IDE terminal I still see the old path.

Any ideas?

I'm running on on ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Don't put path variables in an rc file, use `.profile` (or `.bash_profile` depending on how your system in configured)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the GOPATH settings for GoLand IDE.
Goto `Settings > Go > GOPATH` and check the settings.
Below is the snippet for my system.

[image]

Make sure you have selected "Use GOPATH that's defined in system environment".

Comment: Thanks @Saurav Prakash, but I have this settings already in place.

Comment: I'll accept this answer although it worked for me only when I configured the GOPATH at the project level.